# Landscape 19.10 - Computer Packages error

Tags: landscape

I've installed [Landscape](https://landscape.canonical.com/) (On-Prem) 19.10 on a new Ubuntu 1804LTS installation using quickstart https://docs.ubuntu.com/landscape/en/landscape-install-quickstart.

I've registered a Ubuntu 1804 LTS client successfully however when trying to view packages i.e. 
https://landscapeurl/account/standalone/computer/3/packages 
I get the following error in the app server log

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/publisher/publish.py", line 129, in publish
    obj = request.traverse(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/publisher/browser.py", line 560, in traverse
    ob = super(BrowserRequest, self).traverse(ob)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/publisher/http.py", line 457, in traverse
    ob = super(HTTPRequest, self).traverse(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/publisher/base.py", line 260, in traverse
    obj = publication.traverseName(self, obj, entry_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/app/publication/zopepublication.py", line 198, in traverseName
    ob2 = adapter.publishTraverse(request, nm)
  File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/routes/publisher.py", line 137, in publishTraverse
    view = queryMultiAdapter((self.context, request), name=name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/component/_api.py", line 123, in queryMultiAdapter
    return sitemanager.queryMultiAdapter(objects, interface, name, default)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/interface/registry.py", line 359, in queryMultiAdapter
    objects, interface, name, default)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/interface/adapter.py", line 541, in queryMultiAdapter
    result = factory(*objects)
  File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/ui/package/dashboard.py", line 70, in __init__
    if self._has_no_packages:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/cachedescriptors/property.py", line 71, in __get__
    value = func(inst)
  File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/ui/package/dashboard.py", line 118, in _has_no_packages
    no_packages_count = self._computer_counts["no-packages"]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/cachedescriptors/property.py", line 71, in __get__
    value = func(inst)
  File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/ui/package/dashboard.py", line 109, in _computer_counts
    return self._counts[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/cachedescriptors/property.py", line 71, in __get__
    value = func(inst)
  File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/ui/package/dashboard.py", line 105, in _counts
    return self._search.get_computer_counts()
  File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/model/package/search.py", line 221, in get_computer_counts
    counts = self._get_computer_counts_external()
  File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/model/package/search.py", line 301, in _get_computer_counts_external
    account_id=account_id, computer_ids=computer_ids)
  File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/model/package/client.py", line 38, in query
    return self._query(method, params)
  File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/model/package/client.py", line 58, in _query
    raise PackageSearchConnectionError(str(error))
PackageSearchConnectionError: Error 65: necessary data rewind wasn't possible
```

I can view all other properties for the registered client i.e. Hardware, Processes etc with no errors at all.

Can anyone assist further please, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue; as we have corporate proxy servers,  the "no_proxy" environment variable was missing localhost. I think PYCurl is used behind the scenes for querying package-search service which listens on localhost; looks like it uses the http_proxy, https_proxy and no_proxy environment variables.

Used tcpdump on the lo interface when navigating to 
https://landscapeurl/account/standalone/computer/3/packages. Found packets in that trace requesting name resolution for our corporate proxy servers.

Updated the no_proxy environment variable in /etc/environment bounced the server and its now working